# How to open an infobox on google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried the infobox explained [here](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

My javascript is below. There I have passed the map, marker and the content for the infobox. But it gives me an error saying "TypeError : Object does not support method or property open". I have realized that the exception comes when i tried to open the infobox. Any ideas please..!

```
function addBasicInfoBox(map, marker, contentStr) {
    try {
        var ibOptions = {
                content: contentStr,
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 150,
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                zIndex: 50,
                boxStyle: {
                    background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    width: "280px"
                },
                closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
                closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        };
        var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);
        ib.open(map, marker);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, MOUSE_OVER, function() {
        try {
            //ib.open(map, marker);
        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: What is `MOUSE_OVER` ?

Comment: It's explained [here about Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) by Google Developers itself along with examples. It should be `'mouseover'` instead of `MOUSE_OVER`

Answer (score 0):

Initially try with a simpler info window like,

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

If this works then the library that you are including for InfoBox is not on the correct path. 
Open your map in mozilla, right click and view source. Click on the Infobox.js, I guess it won't open.